# Keeping a PDF article's bibliography always visible

Tags: pdf, preview

While reading an article, I like to keep the bibliography pages at the tail of the article visible at the same time as I am going through the pages of the article.

Two obvious ways for doing this are

1. Open the pdf article twice, once with Preview and another with Adobe Reader.
2. Temporarily make a copy of the article and open both with Preview.

Am I omitting something? Is there really no natural/easier way to do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skim.app has two options.

1. `View Menu > Show Split View` splits the view in half
2. Press the <kbd>CMD</kbd> key and highlight the area of interest. A new mini-window will appear with that part visible, leaving the main window for your reading and scrolling.

Comment: The two obvious solutions, duplicating a pdf file or using two different readers, are both silly. This is indeed Skim's "killer feature". It is as fast as Preview and if there is a difference in the quality of rendering, I cannot see it. My only somewhat negative comment after initial use is that Skim is too conservative with thumbnail rendering, waiting until the user skims to a given section.

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Reader, when reading your document, you can choose "New Window" to view two different spots in the same document.  Do it again if you want to view three spots.